# Arduino AT Cmd Not Working

Tags: arduino-nano, arduino-pro-mini

We are Using I-CUBE-LRWA Lora Module AT Cmd with Arduino ProMini
Set of commands set with DockLight working Perfectly but with Arduino, we are getting some coded response and well every time RXTimeout response.

Docklight Response 
[image]

Arduino Response :

[image]

Arduino Code:

```
mySerial.flush();
lora.flush();
Serial.flush();
digitalWrite(lorapin, HIGH);
delay(500);
lora.listen();
lora.print(“AT\r\n”);
String dr = lora.readStringUntil("\r\n");
delay(10);
Serial.print(“AT:” + dr);
Serial.println();

                lora.print("ATZ\r\n");
                String ATZ = lora.readStringUntil("\r\n");
                delay(10);
                Serial.print("ATZ:"+ATZ);
                Serial.println();


                lora.print("AT+NJM=0\r\n");
                String NJM = lora.readStringUntil("\r\n");
                delay(10);
                Serial.print("AT+NJM:" + NJM);
                Serial.println();


                lora.print("AT+DADDR=as:23:00:00\r\n");
                String DADDR = lora.readStringUntil("\r\n");
                delay(10);
                Serial.print("AT+DADDR:" + DADDR);
                Serial.println();

                lora.print("AT+APPSKEY=90:22:53:85:44:7A:22:32:75:35:26:35:63:30:A9:56\r\n");
                String APPSKEY = lora.readStringUntil("\r\n");
                delay(10);
                Serial.print("AT+APPSKEY:"+APPSKEY);
                Serial.println();


                lora.print("AT+DEUI=5bb1605000032as\r\n");
               String DEUI = lora.readStringUntil("\r\n");
                delay(10);
                Serial.print("AT+DEUI:" + DEUI);
                Serial.println();
                lora.print("AT+NWKSKEY=23:43:67:9A:22:44:22:69:50:67:3A:A3:34:27:26:72\r\n");
                String NWKSKEY = lora.readStringUntil("\r\n");
                delay(10);
                Serial.print("AT+NWKSKEY:" + NWKSKEY);
                Serial.println();


                lora.println("AT+CFM=1\r\n");
                String CFM = lora.readStringUntil("ok\r\n");
                delay(10);
                Serial.print("AT+CFM:" + CFM);
                Serial.println();

                lora.println("AT+ADR=1\r\n");
                String ADR = lora.readStringUntil("\r\n");
                delay(10);
                Serial.println();
                Serial.print("AT+ADR:" + ADR);
                Serial.println();

                lora.print("AT+CLASS=C\r\n");
                String CLASS = lora.readStringUntil("ok\r\n");
                delay(10);
                Serial.print("CLASS:" + CLASS);
                Serial.println();

                lora.print("AT+JOIN\r\n");
                String JOIN = lora.readStringUntil("ok\r\n");
                delay(10);
                Serial.print("JOIN:" + JOIN);
                Serial.println();
                delay(500);

                lora.print("AT+NJS=?\r\n");
                String NJS = lora.readStringUntil("ok\r\n");
                delay(10);
                Serial.print("NJS:" + NJS);
                Serial.println();
                delay(500);


                String sendatavar="AT+SEND=2:30";
                Serial.print(sendatavar);
                Serial.println();
                lora.print(sendatavar);
                delay(10000);
                String sedndr = lora.readStringUntil("rxDone\r\n");
                delay(1000);
                Serial.print("AT+send:" + sedndr);
```

Comment: So how exactly did you connect the hardware? Can you show a photo? Also is this running on an Arduino Nano or Pro Mini? You have added both question tags. What voltage is the Pro Mini running on?

Comment: What Baud rate you used in the Arduino code?

Comment: @Fahad Baud Rate 9600

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt i'm using 5v pro mini

Comment: Can you show a wireup or schematic?

Comment: The COM Output image you posted, the baud rate is showing 57600. Maybe that's why you are seeing garbage output?